# What are alternatives for SLD editor?

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, sld, software-recommendations, geoexplorer

I am working with Geoserver and Geoexplorer and try to create my own sld to style those maps.
I was download osmdata and add layers to map.
 I was try to use Qgis and Udig for styling data,but the problem is MaxScaleDenominator and minScaleDenominator are limited i couldn't set zoom level 1 , 2 , 3 etc in those Software.

Any other software available for SLD editing?

Comment: The following question refers to GUI editors.  Is your question different? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/93622/sld-editor-with-gui

Comment: SLD doesn't support zoom levels so you'll need to work out the scale denominators which ever tool you use.

Answer (score 1):

As per your question

> Any other software available for SLD editing?

Yes, If you are looking for SLD editing tool, there is a extension of Geo Server for styling

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/css/index.html
 and here is the complete guide of CSS cookbook.
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/css/cookbook/index.html

CSS extension it self creates SLD for your shape file, you just need to be aware of CSS.